# sed and regex issue

Tags: regex, sed

I need help performing a sed statement on a file and I can't seem to figure out why what I have isn't working.  I've searched thoroughly, and each result comes up with something similar, however I just don't see why mine does not have the results I expect.

I have a file with several listings like

```
192.168.10.23:7020
192.168.10.23:4520
192.168.10.23:3320
```

etc. and essentially I need to replace 192.168.10.23:XX20 with 192.168.10.23:XX21.

Among others, I've attempted:

```
sed 's/\:\([0-9]\)\{2\}20/\:&21/g' $file
```

which gives results like :

```
192.168.10.23:702021
192.168.10.23:452021
192.168.10.23:332021
```

and also:

```
sed 's/\:\([0-9]\)\{2\}/\:&21/g'
```

which gives results like:

```
192.168.10.23:702120
192.168.10.23:452120
192.168.10.23:332120
```

Other attempts either make no change at all or have a wildly different result.  I feel like I'm so close, yet so far.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The colon isn't a metacharacter in regexes, so you shouldn't need to escape it.  The answers below cover the solution.  You're close, but `&` matches the whole of the string that is matched by the regex; `\1` represents the first part matched inside the first `\(...\)` sequence.

Comment: Thanks!  I think that was my main issue "&" vs. "\1".  I certainly need to study the sed man page & other tutorials more, but this definitely helped me out of a bind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why can't you just

```
sed 's/20$/21/'
```

But also possible, in the spirit of your original solution:

```
sed 's/\(:[0-9]*\)20/\121/'
```

Instead of `&`, it uses `\1`, which only repeats the part matched by the parentheses.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  Your second example worked perfectly.  The first did not, I'm guessing b/c of the missing ":"...there are ports in the file that begin with 20 (and so :2020 does exist) -- an omission on my part, sorry!  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

`sed 's/:\([0-9]\{0,3\}\)20/:\121/g' $file`

Also, I'm assuming your port numbers will be anywhere from 2-digit to 5-digit port numbers.

Example:
http://regexr.com?340vk